# How to get the index for the filepath of a selected file via QFileSystemModel?

Tags: model-view-controller, pyqt

Is there a way to get the file path of the selected file in `QFileSystemModel`?

I found the function `QString QFileSystemModel::filePath ( const QModelIndex & index )` const which returns the file path. But how to find the index of the selected file?

I'm working with PyQT.
I'm have a `QFileSystemModel` created (called model) and it displays all the files and directories correctly. Then I did

```
index = QModelIndex()
print (self.model.filePath(index))
```

trying to print out the filepath of the selected file.But it returned nothing. Anyone know what I need to do for the index?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need to get the index from the view as in this example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui as gui, QtCore as core

app = gui.QApplication([])

model = gui.QFileSystemModel()
model.setRootPath(core.QDir.currentPath())

tree = gui.QTreeView()
tree.setModel(model)
tree.setRootIndex(model.index(core.QDir.currentPath()))

def dummy(item):
    index = tree.currentIndex()
    print model.filePath(index)

tree.clicked.connect(dummy)

tree.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: thanks! I followed this, having the view connected with 'dummy'. Still, it printed out empty paths. Any idea why?